# Display firebase document field to iOS tableview

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

How can one display the data from the Firestore Collections to tableView on Swift?

This code runs (see below) but I want to import directly from the Firestore database instead of hardtyping data:

```
var habits = [Habit(id: "1", author: "Maiuran", text: "heyhey")]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "habitCell", for: indexPath) as! HabitTableViewCell
    cell.set(habit: habits[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

The code below works to print to the console but not sure how to display the

```
  let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Firestore.firestore().collection("habits").whereField("author", isEqualTo: name).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
       if let err = err {
           print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
      } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
           }
      }
   }
```

This is the database: [Firestore Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGPPU.png)

Thank you so much for your time and advice!

Comment: It looks like you haven't yet made an attempt to actually deal with Firestore yet.  Have you read the documentation for reading data out of Firestore? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I tried doing the following @DougStevenson:

Comment: let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("habits").whereField("author", isEqualTo: name).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
           if let err = err {
               print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
               }
          }
       }

Comment: This works and prints to the console, but stuck with displaying it on the actual app :/

Answer (score 1):

You have to check user: if user == nil you must login user before.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if user == nil {
        login()
    } else {
        // processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hoang! That works out, but how do I showcase the information from the Firestore documents into Tableview? I am only able to print them to console right now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution (now it posts to a given UITextfield so just need to figure out how to post to tableView):

```
    Firestore.firestore().collection("habits").getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in

        snapshot!.documents.forEach({ (document) in
            let nametyname = document.data()["author"]
            let street = document.data()["friend"]

            self.myTextiFieldi.text = nametyname as! String
            print(nametyname)
            print(street)
        })
    })
```